# WordPress / Gravity Forms: rg_* to gf_* tables migration

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Long story short, I shutdown my server about 2 years ago and am looking to restore it. I have a valid Gravity Forms license from an old job I still contract with and was told I can keep using it personally as a payment, but not a login for support from them.

I see Gravity Forms had a huge data migration recently. When I restore my site as it was, everything works, but when I update Gravity Forms, it is showing "no forms" for everything.

I am getting the `gf_` tables after updating, but there is no data in it. All the data is in the `rg_` tables.

Is there any way to force the version that does this migration, or away to call for that function? Maybe a way to manually install the plugin version that did it?

Comment: The migration process should be completed automatically during the upgrade. As per [Gravity Forms Docs](https://docs.gravityforms.com/database-storage-structure-reference/#the-migration-process): *The automatic migration process creates the new tables and copies all the data over to the new tables in a series of background tasks. If the task stops, for example, due to a server restart then the migration will continue with a scheduled cron task. If there’s a database error then the migration will stop and try again later.*.

Comment: Yea, I read that as well. I'm sure the update from the version prior to the migration and the one of the migration has all kinds of checks. I don't know how long ago this happened or how far behind I am. Maybe there was a flag or something that I never got.  I restored yesterday morning, so it's been a full 24 hours. I know the cron could run anytime, but looking for some way to ensure it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found version 2.2.2 of gravity forms. Installing this and then doing an update from that version solved it.